# I have to write a program, using the quadratic equation, which asks you to enter values for a, b and c

Tags: python, python-3.x

If b2 < 4ac then the program should tell the user that there are no roots and then terminate. In all other cases the program should simply print out the values of both roots to 3 decimal places.

This is all I've got right now and I don't know why but it says syntax invalid for f= x**2. Please help me out, would be great if you could explain where I went wrong :)

```
import math
x=int(input("enter number a:"))
y=int(input("enter number b:"))
z=int(input("enter number c:"))
r = ((-x+((y**2-(4*x*z)))**1/2)/2*x)
r2= ((-x-((y**2-(4*x*z))**1/2)/2*x)
f= x**2
g= 4*y*z
if g>f:
    print("no roots")
else:
    print("root 1:",r,end=" ")
    print("root 2:",r2)
```

Comment: please post your full error

Comment: File "<string>", line 7
    f= x*x
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Narayani: your line setting `r2` is missing a closing parenthesis `)`. This shows up as an error on the *following* line. While I'd normally consider posting this as an answer, I suspect the question will be closed as a typo pretty quickly.

Comment: In addition, it's been quite a while since I did secondary school math but I'm pretty certain there's only *one* root when `b = 4ac`. Probably no point in delivering two identical values. And why you would use `x/y/z` when every copy of the formula on the entire planet uses `a/b/c` is beyond me :-)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Number one, you have a missing closing missing parenthesis on this line which, in Python, often causes an error to be reported on the following line:

```
r2= ((-x-((y**2-(4*x*z))**1/2)/2*x)
```

Number two, since every copy of the relevant formula on the planet uses `a`, `b`, and `c`, it would be advisable to stick with that since it's what most people will understand.

Number three, you don't need to import `math` here, and you should be checking input for validity *before* performing any calculation on it (and probably allowing for the one-root case).

And, number four, the expression `a ** 1 / 2` is *not* `a` to the power of a half (the square root), it's `a` to the power of `1`, then that divided by `2`.

Taking all that into account, you would get something like:

```
a = int(input("enter number a: "))
b = int(input("enter number b: "))
c = int(input("enter number c: "))

if a == 0:
    print("Zero value for a means it's not a quadratic.")
else:
    root_bit = b * b - 4 * a * c
    if root_bit < 0:
        print("No roots.")
    elif root_bit == 0:
        print("One root:", -b / (2 * a))
    else:
        print("Two roots:", -b + (root_bit ** 0.5) / (2 * a), end="")
        print(" and", -b - (root_bit ** 0.5) / (2 * a))
```

Comment: hey, so when i run the code it is giving me wrong values for the roots. Any idea how i can solve that?

Comment: use the right math :) let me find it really quickly

Comment: @paxdiablo thanks for editing that extra explanation in!

Comment: No probs, Ironkey, I just figured if it was *going* to be answered, we should do the most thorough job possible. Though reading that sentence back, it makes me look very arrogant and self-congratulatory. Which I swear I'm normally not :-)

Comment: and @Ironkey!!!